# Showing the Strong law of large numbers for normal distributed random variables by integration.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

I want to show that for the special case of normally distributed random variables - with mean equal to zero and variance equal to one - the strong law of large numbers holds, by integrating the density function twice.

Let 
\begin{equation}
S_n = \frac{1}{n}(X_1+\dots+X_n); \text{ for  }X_n \in N(0;1) \iff S_n \in N(0;\frac{1}{n})\text{ with density } f(x;n)
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
P(|S_n|>\epsilon)=1- \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} f(x,n)dx = \frac{1}{2}\text{erfc}(\epsilon\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}})
\end{equation}
If we integrate with respect to n, we get for

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}P(|S_n|>\epsilon)dn= \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}
\end{equation}

(I am not sure if I have to integrate from 1 to $\infty$, instead of zero, but the only singularity is at $\epsilon = 0$ no matter where you start integrating)

This implies that for all $\epsilon > 0:\sum_{}^{\infty}$ $P(|S_n|>\epsilon) < \infty$ and there fore $S_n\rightarrow0$ a.s. (using borel-cantelli)

I would be glad if some one can share some advise if this makes sense or not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is correct, but it is perhaps worth mentioning why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|S_n| > \epsilon) \leq \int_0^\infty P(|S_n| > \epsilon)$.

Comment: So in one line we treat $n$ as a natural number of $\mathbb{N}$ but in another line we integrate with respect to it as a $\mathbb{R}$? Isn’t that inconsistent?